# Concentration in Gauss space

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, concentration-of-measure

This is a theorem called Concentration in Gauss space. Let $f$ be a real valued Lipschitz function on $\mathbb {R}^{n}$ with Lipschitz constant $K$, i.e. $\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|\leq K\|x-y\|_{2}$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb {R}^{n}$ (such functions are also called K-Lipschitz). Let $X$ be the standard normal random vector in $\mathbb {R}^{n}$. Then for every $t\geq 0$ one has
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb {P}\left\{f(X)-\mathbb {E}f(X)>t\right\}\leq \text{exp}(-t^{2}/2K^{2}).
\end{align*}
We have 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb {P}\left\{f(X)-\mathbb {E}f(X)>t\right\}=\mathbb {P}\left\{e^{\lambda(f(x)-\mathbb {E}f(x))}>e^{\lambda t}\right\}\leq \mathbb {E}e^{\lambda(f(x)-\mathbb {E}f(x))}/e^{\lambda t}
\end{align*}
I wonder how to continue from here. Or maybe just inform me where to find the proof. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A detailed proof can be found in Ledoux's *The Concentration of Measure Phenomenon*. Much machinery is needed to prove the result (unfortunately). A proof outline can also be found in Vershynin's *High Dimensional Probability* but it's along the same lines as the previous one. An elementary proof of a weaker inequality can be found at slide 49 of [this pdf](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~rdhough/mat639-spring17/lectures/lecture22.pdf).

Comment: Thank you sir! @GabrielRomon